# How do I reshape my data frame into an array of [-1, 1]?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, dataframe

I'm trying to reshape my data frame into an array of `[-1, 1]`.

I've tried

```
z.reshape(-1,1)
```

I need `[-1, 1]` array so that I can scale my data for my time series model.

Comment: Tell us about the data frame.  Shape, size, columns, dtypes, etc.

Answer (score 0):

`df.values` gives you access to the underlying numpy array. Then, use reshape as usual:

```
df.values.reshape(-1, 1)
```